# Browser based client side form filling

Tags: javascript, html, forms, client-side

My organisation provides grants to small civil society organisations in rural Sierra Leone.  We had been using Acrobat forms filled out in Acrobat Reader to collect applications - completed forms are saved to the local hard drive then returned to us by email or on USB stick.  The organisations typically have computers running Windows 95 and up, but not internet connections.

Unfortunately, in a recent review by one of our major donors, it was deemed that requiring the forms be filled out in Acrobat Reader was discriminating against potential applicants that didn't have the software.  This may have been reflected in the large number of hand filled printed forms returned.  We've been told by our major donor we need to use Word for the forms.

My heart sinks when I hear this, and I feel that this is equally discriminatory since Word is not a free product, and who knows what versions of that we have to cater to.  Not only that, but getting data out of a Word form is approaching manual entry.

Plain text would be an option, but it would be nice to lay this out as a form.

I am looking for a method for filling in an HTML form in a browser then saving it to the local hard drive in a text based format.  Has anyone got any ideas for how to achieve this?

To clarify - the form itself would be distributed on USB drives.  We aren't requiring applicants to fill the forms out on Internet connected computers.

I guess if this was easy, there would be no market for a product like InfoPath.  And no - there is zero chance any civil society organisation in Sierra Leone has InfoPath installed :-)

Comment: Ha! Let us say people don't have word? 
What do they say then?

Comment: I'm not really in a position to have the conversation with the donor that starts with "they don't have Word either".  I need to start the conversation with, "We have this option that doesn't require Word either".

Answer (score 3):

If you can deliver the forms via usb stick/cd, or a decent internet connection, I would consider using [Titanium Desktop](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-desktop-application-development/) which is free, and can do exactly what you want, but even better.

Basically, you write your forms in HTML, and you code with some client side javascript to capture that data. Then all this is wrapped in a browser chrome (like a browser without the toolbars and buttons), and you can write files using javascript again, which sends api messages to the browser chrome to actually write the file to the system.

So the final result, is that without much extra work, you can have a custom made app, with all the benefits of web technology, that can save the data in whatever format you like to the local computer.

Comment: +1 That sounds quite promising, although see my reply to David Hedlund.  What additional skills are needed to develop something in Titanium Desktop beyond HTML and javascript?

Comment: Only HTML and JavaScript required. Basically, Titanium Desktop is a browser wrapper, which you create a webpage that goes inside. Any interaction with the browser wrapper, or the operating system is done via API calls from javascript. Just HTML and JavaScript is all you need.

Answer (score 2):

If the computers don't have internet connection, but you want a browser-based application, then you're going to have to have physical access to the clients, to get the prerequisite HTML files there in the first place, correct?

As long as you're able to do that, why not write a simple client desktop application that just presents a windows form and writes the data to disk in any format you'd like?

Comment: I see your point.  Why not?  Lack of experience to do this myself in a timely fashion, and lack of funding to get someone else to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Try using Google-Docs.

They have a good API for forms.

---

Or just include a install file for the reader along with the pdf.

Comment: @dunxd haha how do you expect to fill out an html form without internet access?

Comment: That is the exact nature of the question.  You don't have to have an internet connection to open an HTML file, but you seem to need one to complete an HTML form.

Comment: Neat answer - why didn't I think of that?  Need to check licensing.  Still, I am intrigued to find out if there is a browser based way of doing this, but I think I have a practical solution...